# Is any support supplied for tournaments?

Tags: league-of-legends

Do Riot supply anything in game for tournaments not hosted by them self like ggClassic, like special game modes where every hero and rune is available and all players automatically have access to level 30 perks, or are only items players have unlocked them self available to them during these kinds of tournaments?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean champions? Or things like runes as well?

Comment: @Tristan I'm thinking in general in game items that you normally need to unlock like champions, runes, perks from being max summoner level etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They play on their game accounts so no riot doesn't supply them with anything except on  IEM from what i have seen